# Are there multiple realities in Re:Zero, or is it just one reality rewinding?

Tags: re-zero

For example, in one timeline Subaru kind of screws up- Rem dies and Ram is furious at him and tries to kill him. He ends his life in that timeline by jumping off the cliff, committing suicide. This left me wondering "how would the people from that life continue to live?" Or rather, does that world continue?

Comment: nice job warning about spoilers right after a spoiler in the title :D

Comment: I don't think we'll ever find out, and this is because this way we would have more plausible theories to fantasize about. Authors of such time-rewind works usually don't reveal the exact mechanics. But idk, maybe it's already answered by the author in some interview. My opinion is whatever you think is more interesting, after all it's entertainment and whichever is more fun, is better.

Comment: It is actually a philosophical question. If there are multiple realities, but Subaru can only visit any given reality one time, then that reality is absolutely "gone" once he leaves it.  It can never affect him, nor he it. More generally, look at the real world, Terra. Is it (or our solar system, or our galaxy) fixed to one reality, or does it periodically phase thru one reality to another? Does it matter if we will never know the difference?

Comment: @Hakase it only spoils those that haven't watched the intro OR the first episode OR read any online synopsis. Because once you do, the title is not a spoiler, it is the plot description.

Comment: Wait..  i thought it was like video game where every time he dies he returns to check point.

Comment: @swswsws That's the entire point of this time rewind *or* parallel reality uncertainty − to get us thinking. And look what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning, spoiler-heavy answer.**

There is [break-down of most chapters of light-novel](http://pastebin.com/GbgUPSKZ) (numerous spoilers inside). According to summary of Arc 4,

> author gives a hint, that each timeline, where Subaru dies, may exist even after his death, at least, some events in some timelines are described.

Comment: You seem to be referring to the second trial to liberate the sanctuary. In that trial Subaru experiences the moments following his death across various previous loops. This isn't necessarily confirmation of multiple timelines, the second trial is about a present "that could be". Emilia's second trial shows her still living in the forest with Fortuna and Geuse, this is not a continuation of an existing timeline but a what-if scenario extrapolating from Emilia's experiences, Subaru's could likewise be the unrealized continuations of what "would have" happened had time continued after his death